# Выполнение миграций в консоли yii2

Tags: php, yii2, консоль

Есть проект. В нем есть миграции. 
При разворачивании проекта на новой машине выполняем след. действия:

```
1.php init
2.php yii migrate/up
```

Как `php yii migrate/up` запихнуть в `php init`, чтобы не делать лишние действия?
(На самом деле команд больше, просто для примера привел эти)

Answer (score 1):

Например, создаете контроллер `ProjectController` в консольном приложении, экшн `actionInit()`.

```
public function actionInit()
{
    $this->printHeader('Migration up');
    $this->runMigrationWithMarks();

    $this->printHeader('Init users');
    $this->run('local-users/init-default-users', ['interactive' => 0]);

    $this->printHeader('Set default parameters');
    $this->setDefaultParams();
    ...
}

/**
 * Migration up
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function runMigrationWithMarks()
{
    try {
        ...
        $this->run('migrate/up', ['interactive' => 0]);
        ...
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Прописываете нужные команды, запускаете `php yii project/init`.
Но, `init`, мне кажется, все равно нужно отдельно запускать.